# how to download multiple file from ftp server and store into local folder?

Tags: ssis

suppose i have a local folder on my computer and that contains thousands of record and i want to download all file from FTP and add on that local folder,is that possible? I've never used ftp before, so I am not sure where to start.

Comment: it is your FTP or the remote FTP? can you access to that from your local machine?

Comment: thats my Remote FTP

Comment: you could use `script task`, using C# code `System.IO.File.Move` to download them

Comment: @LONG so we do not have any option by using FTP Task right? i have no idea about C# so

Comment: I will post answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, you definitely could `Execute Process Task`, there are three important fields that you need to take care of(In the `Process` Page of this task)

1. Executable
2. Arguments
3. WorkingDirectory

For the first one, choose any tool that you are using to download the files from FTP. I use `FileZilla` before.

For the `Arguments`, you could either use direct commands or `.txt` script

For the 3rd one, specify where that tool is located.

**UPDATE:**

If you will use `FTP task`, there is one properties called `OverwriteFileAtDestination`, which is default to `false`, so you do not need to worry about it.

Comment: okay, use FTP Task  to download from Remote FTP and retrieve into local folder (lets say Backup Folder) but on my back up folder ,i have lots of file so i can not overwritten, my question is ,is it possible to retrieve data without overwritten?